# How can I perform NMDS (bray-curtis distance) on a large (300k * 10k) dataset?

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-analysis, vegan

I am working with a very large dataset of vegetation cover data (300,000 plots x 10,000 species) that I want to get clustered in vegetation types. My normal workflow would be to perform first an NMDS (bray-curtis distance) and then do a K-means on the NMDS result (to avoid using euclidean distance on a cover dataset).

When I try to run the NMDS on this large dataset, the data are disconnected:

```
NMDS1<-metaMDS(data_wide, distance = "bray",k=5, noshare=TRUE, autotransform = FALSE, trymax=100, maxit=1000, wascores = FALSE)

# Error in cmdscale(dist, k = k) : NA values not allowed in 'd'
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In stepacross(dis, trace = trace, toolong = 0, ...) :
#   Disconnected data: Result will contain NAs
# 2: In metaMDSdist(comm, distance = distance, autotransform = autotransform,  :
#   data are disconnected, results may be meaningless
```

How can I perform this analysis on a dataset of this size?

Answer (score 1):

You may really have problems in running NMDS on dataset that large. However, your error message was not caused by the size of dataset, but for having disconnected data (like the error message says). You specified `noshare=TRUE` which means that the method identifies pairs of sampling units that share nothing between them, and tries to see if there are intermediary sampling units that share something (some species) between both of these extremes, and estimated the distances *via* these intermediary points. However, you had some sampling units that had no such route and this left hyou with disconnected data. You should either turn off this procedure (`noshare=FALSE`) or you should identify disconnected points or disconnected subsets of your data: you really cannot say anything about relations between disconnected subsets of data since they have nothing in common. Function `distconnected` can be used to find these subsets or single aberrant points.